# How to determine mac address of a modem on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, powershell, cable-modem

For a validation process I need to know the MAC address of a cable modem. (I do not need to know the MAC address of the network adapter.) The cable modem though is placed somewhere hardly accessible, so I want to avoid physically touching it to read its sticker.

What I do have is a Windows 7 machine connected to it, so I want to look up its MAC address via power shell. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Why don't you just look at the label on the modem and/or log into the configuration page that contains this information?

Comment: @Ramhound I stated why I do not want to read its sticker. As to the configuration page: I did not know that the device had one.

Comment: @Ramhound It would be nice to know if there is a generic way to get to the MAC address of any modem.

Comment: Are you looking for the WAN MAC or the internal LAN MAC?

Comment: See the [answer](http://superuser.com/a/643590/144147) from @rblake. It worked great for me. I have a Router (Belkin), and a **`ARRIS DOCSIS 3.0 / PacketCable 1.5 Touchstone Telephony Modem, Model: TM722G`** from Comcast. On the first tab on that page ("Status"), under "Interface Parameters", it shows the "LAN MAC" and the "CABLE MAC" addresses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the modem has an assigned IP address, you can find the MAC address using the `ping` and `arp` command:

1. Ping the device: `ping 1.2.3.4`
2. View arp table: `arp -a`

The MAC address information is pulled by the ping command, and the info is temporarily stored in your NIC. The arp command is to show the stored information.

Comment: +1 for a nice generic always working answer. The ARP table is not in the NIC though, but in OS memory.

Comment: arp doesn't list the modem for me, though thankfully the ip listed in another answer does (192.168.100.1). Would it be missing because I have a router sitting between my computer and the modem?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want the WAN MAC address. Many cable modems have a configuration or status page. For Comcast modems, it is typically 192.168.100.1. If your modem is also your router, it will be your LAN gateway address. Here's what I get when I open 192.168.100.1 on my cable modem:

[image: Cable Modem Status Page]

Sorry, I don't know how to do this with powershell.

Answer (score 3):

If the modem has a local address in the LAN you're connected to and you know it, then you could use the `arp` command to see its physical address.

`arp -a` lists all discovered addresses.

For more usage of the `arp` command, you can type `arp /?` in shell.